# grep based on pattern in one specific column

Tags: r

I want to grep the rows that contain the string `hsa` in the V21-column.
Tried something like this: `grep(pattern = "hsa",file$V21)` however, this does not work.

```
  V2                      V10                 V21
1 16 AGCTTCCAGTCGAGGATGTTTACA XF:Z:hsa-miR-30a-5p
2 16 AGTGTGAGTTCTACCATTGCCAAA                    
3 16   AGTGAATTCTACCAGTGCCATA                    
4  0   TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA                    
5 16  GCTTCCAGTCGAGGATGTTTACA XF:Z:hsa-miR-30a-5p
6  0   TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTT  XF:Z:hsa-let-7f-5p
```

output:

```
      V2                      V10                 V21
    1 16 AGCTTCCAGTCGAGGATGTTTACA XF:Z:hsa-miR-30a-5p
    5 16  GCTTCCAGTCGAGGATGTTTACA XF:Z:hsa-miR-30a-5p
    6  0   TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTT  XF:Z:hsa-let-7f-5p
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. What is the problem you see?

Comment: OP probably forgot to embed into `file`? Something like `file[grep(pattern = "hsa",file$V21),]` maybe?